# how to send a null value in a resource nested url in laravel restful api

Tags: php, laravel, rest, restful-url

how to send a null value in a resource nested url in laravel restful api like this:

POST     /foo/{foo?}/bar/{bar_id}/categories

like this : /foo/bar/1/categories

I'm using this resource:

```
route::resource('foo.bar.categories', 'CategoriesController')
```

I tried to set it null in my controller but didn't worked

```
public function store(
        Foo $foo = null,
        Bar $bar,
        Request $request 
    ) {

        //didn't work
    }
```

Comment: Use optional at last not in middle

Comment: Don't put optional field in middle route.

Comment: please arrange your param.. optional MUST be at last.. required must the first.. Request $request, Bar $dorm, Foo $foo = null, $inspection_id = null

Comment: I think laravel resources parameters can't been arranged on my own...